# How do I add to the favorites in Samsung S3 contacts?

Tags: contacts, samsung-galaxy-s-3

I have some favorites in my contacts list, but I don't know how they got there. How do I add more, and how do I remove ones I no longer want?

Comment: Can you go to https://www.google.com/contacts/ and let us know if you see the contacts there? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To favorite a contact:

1. Open `Contacts` app
2. Search for contact to favorite
3. Long-press on contact
4. Select `Add to Favorites`

To remove from favorites, select `Remove from Favorites` for a favorite contact (has a star).

Answer (score 0):

Visit each contact you wish to designate a favorite, and click the Star Icon till lit up.
Then visit the Favorites list, and it's there.

From the Favorites list, click again to clear as a favorite. Bing; it's gone.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that stumped me for a long time and I finally figured it out.  If the star doesn't show when you open your contact it's because your contacts are merged (sim contacts, phone contacts, WhatsApp contacts etc).

Here is what you do:

- click on the contact and when it opens click on the three vertical dots at the top right hand corner.
- Then click on 'Manage Linked Contacts'. This will show you the merges.
- Remove sim, WhatsApp and anything else leaving only the phone contact.  Now when you go back into the contact the star appears and you can mark it as a favorite.

Answer (score -1):

You can also call them and then delete the call before it begins to dial.

Comment: How does that help to remove them from favorites – or make them favorites? If everybody you call gets added/removed here, that feature wouldn't make much sense.